# ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, certificado-ssl, certificado

Buenas tardes si me podrían ayudar estaría muy agradecida.
Estoy desplegando mi web por vps, pero al parecer estoy teniendo problemas al obtener mi certificado por certbot, hice los pasos, y esto fue lo que me arrojo:

Deploying certificate
Successfully deployed certificate for intdrivingacademy.com to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf
Successfully deployed certificate for [www.intdrivingacademy.com](http://www.intdrivingacademy.com) to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf
Congratulations! You have successfully enabled HTTPS on https://intdrivingacademy.com and https://www.intdrivingacademy.com

Pero al ingresar a mi web me sale ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT
esta es mi configuracion de archivo en /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
server
{
        server_name intdrivingacademy.com www.intdrivingacademy.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
        }

}
```

y luego de hacer el certificado me modifico o agrego el archivo en /etc/nginx/sites-enable

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_reject_handshake on;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ;
    ssl_reject_handshake on;
    server_name intdrivingacademy.com; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/intdrivingacademy.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/intdrivingacademy.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    return 444;


}

server {
    if ($host = intdrivingacademy.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name intdrivingacademy.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl ;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ;
    ssl_reject_handshake on;
    server_name www.intdrivingacademy.com; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/intdrivingacademy.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/intdrivingacademy.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    return 444;


}
```

Que puedo hacer. si alguien me pudiera ayudar lo agradecería mucho